# PDO Error Message

Tags: php, pdo

CODE:

```
$DBH = new PDO("dblib:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", "$user", "$pass");
$DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,  PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

$sql="select xSupplier, Suppliername, SupplierType from ApSupplier";
echo $sql."<br>";
try {
   $STH = $DBH->query("$sql");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'error message: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

echo "<br>";
print_r($DBH->errorInfo());
//  $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$i=1;
while($row = $STH->fetch()):
   echo $row["Supplier"]."<br>";
   $i++;
   if ($i>10) { exit; }
endwhile;
```

When I execute this statement, I purposly put an x in front of Supplier to make it bomb out. When I do this I get this error message:

> error message: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 207 General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server [207] (severity 16) [select xSupplier, SupplierName, SupplierType from ApSupplier]

So Going and looking up 207 its invalid column name.

My question is how do I get it to tell me the code name and also which column name is bombing out on.

Comment: `query($sql);` remove the quotes

Comment: So you want a Custom Error message that tells you the exact column that caused the error, instead of the `General error:`? also, you tagged `mysql`, but have `new PDO("dblib:...` and `SQL Server error:`?

Comment: Yes. I would like it to mimic the echo $link->error in mysql

Thanks I didnt mean to tag mysql. Meant to tag mssql (bad eyes lol)

Comment: Also remove the quotes from connection user and password: ..."$user", "$pass")